# Forms authentication and Federation Authentication(Single Sign On + ADFS 2.0 + SAML) in Same ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0, ws-federation

We are having one web site which is developed in ASP.NET and VB code base and It has the normal forms authentication with username and password.

One of our client whats to setup the Single Sign On with our web site and they set up ADFS and gave us the Metadata xml file and We have created STS reference to that url and shared our website Metadata for them to add Relying party Trust.

when I access our website it redirecting to customer page and once they enter the login credentials and it's coming back with the Claims which is good.

Problem :

1).Now who ever access our website all user is automatically redirect to client ADFS login page which should not happen.Users should be Prompt with Our login page and it shouldn't automatically re-direct to client ADFS. If user  Wants to use the SSO then it should be re-directed to client page ? How to handle that in programmatic ?

2).If one more client also wants to use the SSO with their IDp then how to configure more than one IDP for One web site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WIF or OWIN?

WIF by default protects all pages.

You could un-protect your login page (location tag) and then if SSO redirect to a dummy protected page which will cause WIF to kick in.

Beware: for older apps. WIF and FBA in the same app. can cause problems.

The classic way to handle 2) is to federate the two ADFS. Then a user will see a Home Realm Discovery screen and get to chose which IDP.